# Why is this check constraint triggering?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

So, I have a metadata table:

```
CREATE TABLE Tables (
      schemaName SYSNAME
    , objectName SYSNAME
    , columnName SYSNAME
    , RowColAgg VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
    , AggFunction NVARCHAR(128)
    )
```

And a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ColumnValidate (
      @schemaName SYSNAME
    , @objectName SYSNAME
    , @columnName SYSNAME
    , @RowColAgg VARCHAR(3)
    , @AggFunction NVARCHAR(128)
    )
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Valid TINYINT = 1
    SET @Valid = @Valid & ISNULL((SELECT 1 WHERE @RowColAgg IN ('Row','Col','Agg')),0)
    IF (@Valid = 1)
    BEGIN
        /* If this is an Aggregate Column, it must have an aggregate function attached */
        IF (@RowColAgg = 'Agg') SET @Valid = @Valid & ISNULL((SELECT 1 WHERE @AggFunction IS NOT NULL),0)
        IF (@Valid = 1)
        BEGIN
            /* If this is an Aggregate or Column header, ensure this is the only one. */
            IF (@RowColAgg IN ('Agg','Col')) SET @Valid = @Valid ^ (SELECT SIGN(COUNT(columnName)) FROM Tables WHERE schemaName =  @schemaName AND objectName  = @objectName AND RowColAgg  = @RowColAgg)
            IF (@Valid = 1)
            BEGIN
                /* If this is a row header, ensure that this is only selected once. */
                IF (@RowColAgg = 'Row') SET @Valid = @Valid ^ (SELECT SIGN(COUNT(columnName)) FROM Tables WHERE schemaName =  @schemaName AND objectName  = @objectName AND columnName  = @columnName AND RowColAgg  = @RowColAgg)
                IF (@Valid = 1)
                BEGIN
                    /* Finally, ensure the names passed bind to the schema. (anti-injection) */
                    SET @Valid = @Valid & (SELECT SIGN(COUNT(*)) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schemaName AND C.TABLE_NAME = @objectName AND C.COLUMN_NAME = @columnName)
                END
            END
        END
    END
    RETURN @Valid
END
```

Which is used in the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Tables ADD CONSTRAINT chkValidEntry
CHECK (ColumnValidate(schemaName, objectName, columnName, RowColAgg, AggFunction) = 1)
```

Now, using select statements, I can see that the function validates the intended rows as = 1:

```
SELECT ColumnValidate('Common', 'ShiftInfo', 'ShiftMonth', 'Col', NULL);--1
SELECT ColumnValidate('Common', 'ShiftInfo', 'ShiftId', 'Agg', 'count');--1
SELECT ColumnValidate('Common', 'ShiftInfo', 'ShiftYear', 'Row', NULL);--1
```

(So yes, the schema check is succeeding in the test environment for the names provided)
However, my insert statements all fail because of the check constraint:

```
INSERT INTO Tables (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('Common', 'ShiftInfo', 'ShiftMonth', 'Col', NULL);
INSERT INTO Tables (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('Common', 'ShiftInfo', 'ShiftId', 'Agg', 'count');
INSERT INTO Tables (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('Common', 'ShiftInfo', 'ShiftYear', 'Row', NULL);
```

For further info: @@VERSION =

```
    Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64) 
    Jun 11 2012 16:41:53 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
```

Why is the constraint triggering when the condition in check should be coming out as true?

Comment: Interesting discrepency. Not obvious. Do you know you can debug your INSERT statements in SSMS? That should allow you to step through the constraint function and you will see which clause is failing validation.

Comment: I'd abandon this and try it do it declaratively. Trying to do this type of thing in check constraints referencing UDFs is problematic. You need to consider the effect of multi row updates/inserts and whether it is run under snapshot isolation or otherwise. Can you state in plain English what it's supposed to do so we don't have to pick apart your obscure use of bitwise operators and `sign`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I somewhat disagree. A table constraint will run against all rows in a multi-row update/insert. The posted function is basically a complex unique constraint...and unique table constraints run without problems in multi-row updates/inserts. That said, I agree the OP can likely accomplish the validation in other more efficent or robust ways.

Comment: @mdisibio Check constraints referencing UDFs are evaluated RBAR not at the end of the statement which means they can fail transactions which ought to succeed. This does not happen with inbuilt unique constraints. Also inbuilt constraints are coded correctly to work irrespective of isolation level (which this one isn't). Maybe the OP can achieve what they need more efficiently and correctly with (say) a unique filtered index or indexed view but I have no intention of reverse engineering the requirement from that to find out.

Comment: @MartinSmith Okay. I believe you, but don't understand fully what is bad about the row-by-row evaluation (if a row fails the UDF constraint then shouldn't the transaction also fail?) SQL BOL clearly states that scalar UDF's can be used for CHECK constraints. However, I don't want to derail this post. Could you perhaps post a link to some documentation that explains what you are pointing out? If not, no worries...Also, I am sure you are right about isolation level.

Comment: @mdisibio I'm on an ipad so won't give complete code. Gist of the problem though is say you have a table `T` with column `C` that is supposed to be unique. The table contains two rows with values 1 and -1. You do `UPDATE T SET C = -C`. After first row is updated temporarily the unique constraint is violated as both rows have same value. But transaction shouldn't fail for that and for inbuilt unique constraint it wouldn't but for a unique constraint implemented this way it can.

Comment: @mdisibio [Unique Constraint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QPrxo.png) - Works correctly. [Home Made Check Constraint](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lcfUN.png) - Doesn't.

Comment: @MartinSmith Excellent examples and explanation. Prompted me to do some more research as well. Learned another Sql Server valid construct to avoid or at least be cautious of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just deleted my comment that the constraint runs before the data is inserted because that is incorrect. The simple fact is that the INSERT statement inserts the values into the `Tables` table and then the constraint check runs. (Just tested with the debugger. I'm sure that behavior is documented somewhere as well.) 
So very simply, your dry run tests succeed because there is no data in the table. But the `INSERT`s add the row, and then fails on your various validations that a previous row with one or more of the same values does not exist.

To see this behavior, add the following line to the function, and then debug:

```
/* If this is an Aggregate or Column header, ensure this is the only one. */
    DECLARE @cnt int = (SELECT COUNT(columnName) FROM Tables WHERE schemaName =  @schemaName AND objectName  = @objectName AND RowColAgg  = @RowColAgg)
```

You will see that @cnt is 1 because the fields were already inserted, and therefore the test fails.

I cannot yet verify my claim that the constraint runs after the insert. Trying to do some research into MartinSmith's comments, I found this post about [Constraints calling UDF's](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/12/17/be-careful-with-constraints-calling-udfs.aspx) which sets up a scenario very similar to yours. The comments are worth reading. Adam Mechanic points out exactly what Martin was saying about the udf being evaluated row-by-row.

**Revised suggestions:**
Your udf is basically a set of conditional unique constraints. All of the rules you posted can be enforced as simpler CHECK constraints or indexed views that will work in a set-based mode, thus eliminating the need to work around the unexpected behavior you came across and to check for 'the first row being okay':
The first two validations can be reduced to simple non-udf check constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE Tables 
(
    schemaName SYSNAME,
    objectName SYSNAME,
    columnName SYSNAME,
    RowColAgg VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL, 
    AggFunction NVARCHAR(128),
    CONSTRAINT [Chk_RowColAgg_IsValid] CHECK(RowColAgg='Row' OR RowColAgg='Agg' OR RowColAgg='Col'),
    CONSTRAINT [Chk_AggHasFn] CHECK((RowColAgg='Agg' AND AggFunction IS NOT NULL) OR (RowColAgg!='Agg'))
)
GO
```

The next two validations can be enforced by indexed views:

```
CREATE VIEW UniqueTablesAggregateOrColumn
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT schemaName, objectName, RowColAgg FROM dbo.Tables WHERE RowColAgg = 'Agg' OR RowColAgg = 'Col';
GO    
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_UniqueAggOrCol ON dbo.UniqueTablesAggregateOrColumn(schemaName, objectName, RowColAgg);
GO
```

and

```
CREATE VIEW UniqueTablesRow
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT schemaName, objectName, columnName, RowColAgg FROM dbo.Tables WHERE RowColAgg = 'Row';
GO    
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_UniqueTablesRow ON dbo.UniqueTablesRow(schemaName, objectName, columnName);
GO
```

Your insert tests will now succeed on the first run, and fail and subsequent repeats.

The final validation is a check against schema's of existing tables. I guess this potentially could be left as udf constraint, or more appropriately in an UPDATE/INSERT trigger.

Comment: Huh, thanks. I hadn't thought that the order was insert then check. I switched up my function to use a direct count and use a bitwise OR. Now results in 1 on the first insert for the desired types, and update statements that would violate are also appropriately being stopped. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a suggestion for a more robust and correct validation. MartinSmith's comments are quite valid, and although you've solved your immediate problem by adding a count, the overall approach ought to avoid the UDF for your particualar case.

Comment: Good points. While the table's not meant for high traffic, I hadn't considered schema-bound unique indexes on views. This will let me do a bit more with it. Thanks for the feedback.